# How to restore a PostgreSQL database from dump file in dbeaver?

Tags: postgresql, dump, dbeaver

In our company we have a dump of PostgreSQL database - file `db.sql`. It weighs 8 Gigabyte. How to restore this database in DBeaver? And we don't have another databases in DBeaver 7.0.5.

I have digged all Internet and haven't found anything how to do this without another database/

Comment: Just use `psql`

Comment: We don't have psql(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you right click on the database you want to restore into, under "Tools" you will find "execute script".  This is how you restore a plain-format dump file, which is what `db.sql` probably is.

This will require you to have `psql`, but dbeaver will offer to download and install its own copy of it for you.

Comment: I tried to use it locally with 200mb file and I couldn't do it. DBeaver just freezes for hours... I had to do it from console and it completes in few seconds.

Comment: @zoran  Works for me.  You will have to do some basic debugging.  What are the OS and versions of everything?  What activity is happening (CPU, disk, memory) on server machine?  and the client machine?

Answer (score 5):

Create a new DB and right click on the db, click on tools and restore. Choose your dump and import it.